# UIScrollView appears with white space that scrolls away on touch

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

In a project I'm working on, the scroll view appears with a white bar that appears after touching it, but continues to partially scroll up even though its not supposed to. The problem is pretty hard to explain but self explanatory if you see the app. You can see my project here: [github.com/rileylloyd24/Test1](http://github.com/rileylloyd24/Test1)

Comment: you don't want to scroll up automatically ? Or appear without a white bar?

Comment: @simalone I want to be able to page left and right only, but there is white space that shows up when the app first launches, and you can still scroll up to it, and the view will bounce down to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently iOS 7 is known for having issues with the insets of scrollviews while using navigation bars. The fix is to implement the following line of code after the `[super viewDidLoad];`

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```